# Why am I able to modify object pointed by const reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants

```
class Counter { 

int count;

void setCount() 
{
 this->count=10;
}

//declaration
friend  const Counter& operator+=( Counter &a, Counter &b); 
}
//definition
const Counter& operator+=(Counter &a, Counter &b) {

a.count = a.count + b.count;

return a;//returning reference to object a with const which makes object             //pointed by ref. a read only in calling function
 }

main() {
Counter c1,c2;
(c1+=c2);    
c1.setCount();     
}
```

main() line 2 :invokes opearator+= function and gets reference to readonly     object  since it returns  const Counter&

My question is ,
in main() line 3 :why am I allowed to change state/attributes of c1 now? I  did return it as const reference in += operator.Please explain

Answer (score 5):

Just because your operator+= returns a const reference to a Counter, it doesn't make `c1` a const Counter.

If you tried to do `(c1+=c2).setCount()`, that would fail, since it would attempt to call the non-const setCount method on the const reference to `c1` returned by operator+=

Side note: the second argument to operator+= should probably be a const reference...

Answer (score 0):

c1 is *not* a const. You declared it in main() line 2 as a normal Counter, so it is modifiable.

The function is not considered a const function, because the keyword is not at the end. Use `Counter& operator+=(Counter &a, Counter &b) const` to declare the function that way (and you will get an error when compiling, that `a.count = a.count + b.count;` is not allowed on const objects).

Comment: Since the function is declared as friend and not member, you actually want `const Counter& operator+=(const Counter& a, Counter& b)` to have a be const

Comment: Thanks What I wanted to do is to return reference to read-only object. I tried a member function const int* getCount() {return &count;} and it gave me read only int in the main. Also compiler forced me to have const int* in main() rather than int *. So I want to know what exactly the difference is.

Comment: Even if the function were const, later `c1.setCount();` is still legal

Answer (score -2):

First if all `C1` is not declared as a `const-variable`.
What you are doing in line 2 in main() is invoking ultimately `assignment` operator on `C1` i.e. `C1 = C1+C2`. It accepts a `const-refernce` of `Counter` Type - but since you didn't defined assignment operator, compiler will do it for you! Hence, It is possible to call non-const member function on `C1`.

Comment: line 2 is invoking `operator+=`, which was defeind by OP. There is no implicit definition of `operator+=` anyway.